# Unable to run Flask from Terminal, “No module named 'my_app’”

Tags: python, flask

I was expecting to get the following, but I’m just stuck at this point.

```
* Serving Flask app "app"
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

In the terminal, I tried running `FLASK_APP=run.py flask run`, then get

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_app’

When I tried changing the name in the command to `FLASK_APP=__init__.py flask run`, I get

> Error: Failed to find application in module “myProject”.  Are you sure it contains a Flask application?  Maybe you wrapped it in a WSGI middleware or you are using a factory function.

Here's my project structure:

```
myProject/
    |—my_app/
        |— source/
            |— __init__.py
            |— other .py files
        |— static/
        |— templates/
    |— __init__.py
    |— someFile.sqlite
    |— run.py
```

`myProject/run.py` contains two lines of code:

```
from my_app import app 
app.run()
```

`myProject/__init__.py` contains nothing, blank.

`myProject/source/__init__.py` is also blank (but I guess these files just need to be here?)

I'm having trouble running the files under PyCharm, but when I run the file run.py in Spyder Anaconda, I get the expected message stating the server is running.  Why is it working on Spyder, but not on PyCharm?

Comment: So there's no `__init__.py` file in `my_app/`? Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: `from my_app import app`—in what file is is `app` defined?

Comment: Sorry, I do have __init__.py in my_app/.  I'm using Python 3.

Comment: app is defined in myProject/run.py

Comment: I don't think so. In your question you say that `myProject/run.py` contains two lines, and you show them here. Neither _defines_ `app`; in fact the first tries to _import_ it from `my_app`. The problem is that I don't see it in `my_app`. There doesn't appear to be anything to import.

Comment: [Please don't add "solved" to your title or question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/248627). Instead, [mark an answer correct by clicking on the checkmark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/248627). You can also [add your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it if none of the ones you received solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Before entering the topic, you should create a `__init__.py` under the `my_app` folder, it will turn it into a python package, so it can be imported.

When you execute `flask run`, flask will look for `app` instance in the module you specify with `FLASK_APP`, so `app.run()` is not needed in this situation.

What you need do?

1. Delete `run.py`.
2. Set `FLASK_APP` to the module name/import path where you create the flask `app` instance (maybe `my_app.source`).
3. Then just do `flask run`.

Comment: This may be necessary later, but for now the problem is "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_app’". I don't think this answer helps with that.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution to the problem: PyCharm → preferences → project interpreter → (there wasn't flask installed) so I hit the `+` button to add package, searched for flask and installed it. After closing preferences, I came back and ran run.py and it worked!

The reason I knew that the package was missing from the interpreter I was using was because when I ran run.py, I would get

```
…/.conda/envs/python3.6/bin/python: No module named flask.
```

I had noticed that in the terminal when I ran `pip show flask`, it gave me the location of where it's installed:

```
Location: /Users/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages.
```

Upon looking at the two path locations, I determined that the interpreter wasn't looking in the correct place so when I changed the path, it started working.

Also, I didn't have to use any commands in the terminal to start the server. I only ran the run.py file.

Comment: Alternatively, you could do `python3 run.py`